# docker-compose: define mount for bind mount and managed mount

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm using docker-compose for defining my service. In docker, there are two concepts for docker volume. Firstly is about `bind mount`: mount on host storage.

```
docker run -d --name web-app -v $HOST/location:/container/location -p 80:80 httpd:latest
```

Secondly is about `managed mount`: abstract storage, not depend on host.

```
docker run -d --name web-app -v /container/location -p 80:80 httpd:latest
```

I want to map those concepts to docker-compose. It means how can I define `bind mount` and `managed mount` when using docker-compose.

Comment: Check https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/volumes-volumedriver

Comment: No offense, but you ask a lot of fundamental questions about how to use Docker Compose. I suggest you start going through the Docker Compose overview, it explains all of the basic concepts you're asking about: https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can find these Docker concepts in the `volumes` section of Docker Compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/volumes-volumedriver

Examples:

```
volumes:
  # Just specify a path and let the Engine create a volume
  - /container/location

  # Specify an absolute path mapping
  - ./myfolder/location:/container/location
```

Comment: do you know what syntax would work for the `volumes:` tag in the root of the `.yml` file?

Your solution will only work for the `volumes:` tag nested under a `services:` tag.

Comment: As far as I understand only named volumes are supposed to be listed in the top level volumes key. "named volumes" are a special method of persisting data for a container, in contrast to bind-mounts or tmpfs mounts.
https://docs.docker.com/storage/

Answer (score 115):

Below is the configuration for both types. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  web:
    image: httpd:latest
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: $HOST/location
        target: /container/location
      - type: volume
        source: mydata
        target: /container/location
volumes:
  mydata:
```

Comment: The documentation link did not work for me, bout found the information here: https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#volumes

Comment: Can you not specify a specific source location for volumes?

Comment: @NoName : For bind mount yes. For volume, you can't specify specific source location. It's fully managed by docker.

Answer (score 9):

I know it's late to answer but I'm mostly writing this for the community.

### Answer:

You only need to do it like this:

```
    volumes:
       - ./root/instantclient_12_2/ojdbc8.jar:/etc/kafka-connect/jars/ojdbc8.jar
       - type: bind
         source: $HOST/etc
         target: /kernel-etc
```

Then, for running it in 'easy to debug mode' do it first with `docker-compose up` and when you made sure it was working fine put a ring on it by adding a `-d` at the end.

### **Important Notes**

1-Make sure your `docker-compose` version is at least `3.2` and in my case, it is`3.7`.
for updating and getting rid of the old version do as below:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker-compose
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.23.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

Source: https://github.com/10up/wp-local-docker/issues/58#issuecomment-476786006

2- Don't forget to `rm` your old container so you don't face weird port-related issues.
heres how:

```
docker container stop YOUR_CONTAINER_ID
docker container rm YOUR_CONTAINER_ID
```

Good luck.

Comment: Confused a bit: you mean docker compose version for `yaml` file and not `docker-compose` itself. As of now latest docker compose is 2.11.2. And you used 1.23.2

Comment: @EugenKonkov No problem my friend, here's the link to versioning i meant. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/

Answer (score 2):

As of Docker 3 on OSX, I had to disable Experimental Feature gRPC and restart as per:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4171

Comment: @dippas That's what the issue says to do "disable Experimental Feature gRPC" There's not a lot more context