# Can't set volume value right when running owncloud docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, owncloud

I followed [this guide](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.0/admin_manual/installation/docker/) to install owncloud server on my VPS, it works. However there is an issue when I was trying to mount the file volume to host server. Below is the `docker-compose.yml` file I use. If I run the docker image with the yml file directly, I can't find there is any owncloud data under the directory `/mnt/data` of my VPS even I created `/mnt/data` manually.

```
version: '2.1'

volumes:
  files:
    driver: local
  mysql:
    driver: local
  backup:
    driver: local
  redis:
    driver: local

services:
  owncloud:
    image: owncloud/server:${OWNCLOUD_VERSION}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${HTTPS_PORT}:443
      - ${HTTP_PORT}:80
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      - OWNCLOUD_DOMAIN=${OWNCLOUD_DOMAIN}
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_TYPE=mysql
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_NAME=owncloud
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_USERNAME=owncloud
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_PASSWORD=owncloud
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_HOST=db
      - OWNCLOUD_ADMIN_USERNAME=${ADMIN_USERNAME}
      - OWNCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      - OWNCLOUD_UTF8MB4_ENABLED=true
      - OWNCLOUD_REDIS_ENABLED=true
      - OWNCLOUD_REDIS_HOST=redis
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/bin/healthcheck"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - files:/mnt/data

  db:
    image: webhippie/mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=owncloud
      - MARIADB_USERNAME=owncloud
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=owncloud
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=owncloud
      - MARIADB_MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET=128M
      - MARIADB_INNODB_LOG_FILE_SIZE=64M
      - MARIADB_INNODB_LARGE_PREFIX=ON
      - MARIADB_INNODB_FILE_FORMAT=Barracuda
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/bin/healthcheck"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - backup:/var/lib/backup

  redis:
    image: webhippie/redis:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - REDIS_DATABASES=1
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/bin/healthcheck"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - redis:/var/lib/redis
```

So I tried modifying line `files:/mnt/data` to `files:/mnt/data:/mnt/data`, then it prompted me with following error.

```
ERROR: for ownclouddockerserver_owncloud_1  Cannot create container for service owncloud: invalid bind mount spec "ownclouddockerserver_files:/mnt/data:/mnt/data": invalid mode: /mnt/data

ERROR: for owncloud  Cannot create container for service owncloud: invalid bind mount spec "ownclouddockerserver_files:/mnt/data:/mnt/data": invalid mode: /mnt/data
```

Can anyone help me out to figure out the right way of mounting external directory to container's? Much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried putting the full path in ?

e.g. /my/external/directory:/mnt/data 

Also are you running on Windows or Linux ? You can get mount issues if you are running on Windows 7 inside virtual box. It only likes mounts within certain user directories from memory.

Comment: try this answer first, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299514/docker-compose-define-mount-for-bind-mount-and-managed-mount

Comment: @PaulNUK thank you for your suggestions. yes, full path, and from the path I think you've already know I'm running on LInux.

Comment: Did anyone actually have an accepted answer for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The `/mnt/data` directory exists only inside your docker container.
It is mapped to a generated (virtual) drive called ***files***.

In order to map the `/mnt/data` directory to a local directory, you use:
`/my/local/directory:/mnt/data`