# docker-compose: how to specify a volume is a bind mount

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file that needs to specify an external bind mount from the host os filesystem.  I have tried to two ways, but in both cases I get error messages.

The first way:

```
volumes:
  type=bind
  source:  /opt/Test_Data/
  target:  test-data
```

ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here in "./docker-compose.yaml", line 17, column 9

The second way:

```
volumes:
  type=bind, source="/opt/Test_Data/", target=/test-data
```

ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yaml', volume must be a mapping, not a string.

---

This is the complete docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  srv1:
    build:
      context: /opt/P01_SH/Dockerfiles/
      dockerfile: /opt/P01_SH/Dockerfiles/Dockerfile

volumes:
   test-data: 
       name: /opt/Test_Data/

volumes:
  type=bind, source="/opt/Test_Data/", target=/test-data
```

This is the complete Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN echo $PATH
WORKDIR "/opt/P01_SH/Dockerfiles/"
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV PATH="$PATH:/opt/P01_SH/Dockerfiles/"
VOLUME /test-data

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gdb
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nasm

SHELL [ "bin/bash", "-c" ]
WORKDIR "/opt/P01_SH/Dockerfiles/"
```

I know that a bind mount can be specified in a docker run command from the command line, as shown in https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts, but I want to do it in the docker-compose.yaml file.

Another person had a similar question at [docker-compose: define mount for bind mount and managed mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299514/docker-compose-define-mount-for-bind-mount-and-managed-mount), but following the first answer I get the error above.

I also saw "Use a bind mount with compose" at https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts and I followed the format there and got the error shown above.  I also tried the dash-indent formatting shown there, but got an indentation error.

So my question is, how do I specify a bind mount in the docker-compose.yaml file shown above?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In the first format, `type: bind` as a YAML mapping entry.  You can also use the short format `/opt/Test_Data:/test-data` as a single list entry, with no YAML keys.  Also see the [`volumes:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes) Compose file documentation.

Comment: It's also attached to a specific service; the `volumes:` block needs to be indented to be underneath `srv1:`.  I wouldn't try to use tricks to create a Docker named volume that's actually a bind mount, just use the more direct bind-mount syntax.

Comment: The documentation provides [examples that you can follow](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes).

Comment: I just posted a follow-up question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77661664/errors-creating-bind-mount-in-docker-compose-file.